# Problems in update Google Analytics v2 to v3

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, ios7

I'm trying to update the Google Analytics version.

I have already read the doc https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/migration.
I'm using the most simple tracking in each page but it's not working.

In version 2 it was working.

In my appDelegate I have this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary    *)launchOptions
{

    [GAI sharedInstance].optOut = YES;
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 120;
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    [[GAI sharedInstance].logger setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

    return YES;
}
```

In my rootViewController I had this code:

```
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:ANALYTICSID];
[tracker sendView:@"Root View"];
```

and I changed for this:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:@"Root View" value:@"Root View value"];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView]  build]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `kGAIScreenName` instead of `@"Root View"`.

`[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Root View value"];`

Comment: But if I use "kGAIScreenName" I get the error "Use of undeclared identifier kGAIScreenName".

Comment: Isn't this variable a simple NSstring?

Comment: That's an NSString which is an identifier that represents the action, in this case you're sending the "ScreenName" like in "sendView:" call. Just include these #import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"

Comment: Hi @Eugene, I included the both files in my header class, but it seem not be tracked.

Comment: I'm'getting just one log line.
    2013-09-29 17:20:35.022 Runner Tools[2648:60b] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002

Comment: Is that line a crash log?

Comment: No, It's a info log. I get just this line when I run the app.
I think if Analytics was working I should get more log lines.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the relation between these lines and the problem you were facing. Could you please connect the dots for me?

Comment: I'm following a steps that you said me, I'm not getting errors in code but the data aren't going to analytics.
I just pasted the log line because it is the unique log line that appear in my console. Don't appear any other log line informing that the data was sent to analytics.
So I don't know where is the error, why the data aren't sent to Google.
Do you have some idea?
Thanks for your attention

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is that you don't really initialize the `deafultTracker` instance. Add this `[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:ANALYTICSID];` into your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Comment: I got it. 

I just inserted the this line in my code:
    [tracker dispatch];

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Sorry, this line was added

    [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, but it should work without directly sending dispatch command. There's such thing as dispatchInterval which actually calls this command, in your case every 120 seconds to send all the analytics data in a batch, so when you have something like 50 events they don't get one by one but in a one batch